# Next js 13 Authentication with HTTP cookie

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, cookies, jwt

I am creating a web app with Next js 13.4.7, I am doing an authentication with JWT token taken from backend (Laravel), and I try to store it in http-only cookie.

I have this two functions in a cookie.ts file (helper functions), one for setting the cookie after I get from backend and one to get the cookie from the browser.

```
export const setAuthToken = (
    expiresIn: number,
    accessToken: string | null,
    baseUrl: string
) => {
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/login`, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ expiresIn, accessToken }),
    });
};

export const getAccessTokenCookie = async (baseUrl: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/login`, {
        method: "get",
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data, "data");

    return data.token;
};
```

Function setAuthToken makes a fetch Request to this file /app/api/auth/login/route.ts

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
    const { expiresIn, accessToken } = body;
    cookies().set({
        name: "access_token",
        value: accessToken,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        sameSite: "strict",
        maxAge: expiresIn,
        path: "/",
    });
}

export async function GET() {
    const accessToken = cookies().get("access_token");
    console.log(accessToken, "accessToken");

    if (!accessToken?.value) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ token: null }), {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
    }
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ token: accessToken.value }), {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });
}
```

The POST request in *setAuthToken* helps creating a storing the cookie, but when I try then to get it through *getAccessTokenCookie* no cookie is found, even in GET function in route.ts file

Answer (score 1):

This cookies instance is read-only. To set cookies, you need to return a new Response using the Set-Cookie header.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#cookies

Answer (score 0):

Add the following return statement to your post method:

```
return new Response(JSON.stringify({success:true}));
```